# Xuggler: Can we write text on video?

Tags: video, xuggler

I need to write text on video based on time. e.g. If I have 30 seconds video then I have to write text every 5th and 20th second. Can it be possible through xuggler media api?
I have tried with ffmpeg command but am not able to write text on video. I have tried the following 2 commands:

```
ffmpeg -i Lake.wmv -filter:v "drawtext=fontsize=30:box=1:text='Stack Overflow':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2" c1.wmv

ffmpeg -i MAIN.mp4 -vf drawtext="text='Text to write':fontsize=20:fontcolor=black" MAIN1.mp4
```

I am testing it on windows version. Please help me to solve this problem.

Please suggest to me how I can write text on video.

Answer (score 0):

try this one is for write text by first 30 seconds C:>ffmpeg -i uno.flv -vf drawtext="fontfile=tahoma.ttf:text='Text to write':fontsize=20:fontcolor=black:x=10:y=10:enable='between(t,1,30)'" dos.flv